# If you have ten boxes and each one has a 10% chance to contain a prize what's the probability to win at least one prize

Tags: probability

This question has been haunting me for quite some time now. I would love to learn the answer.

The Question again:
If you have ten boxes and each one has a 10% chance to contain a prize what's the probability to win at least one prize

Comment: Fun fact.  About 65 percent.  If the prob is 1/n and you do it n times the probability will get closer and close to about 62% the larger n is.  At n = 10 the problem is just over 65%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of winning at least one prize is $1$ minus the probability of winning no prizes.

Assuming you open all the boxes, the probability that none of the boxes contain a prize is $(0.9)^{10}$, so therefore the probability of winning at least one prize is $1 - (0.9)^{10}$.